# Textual description of regexp

Tags: regex

Is there some function/algorithm to create textual description of regexp? For example

- `([a-z]+)` -> *"small letters only"*
- `([0-9]{1,40})` -> *"1 to 40 digits only"*
- `([a-z])([0-9]{5})` -> *"small letter followed by 5 digits"*

etc

Comment: If you're familiar with Perl, YAPE::Regex::Explain is nice: http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm

Comment: Aslo see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772594/regular-expression-explained-with-words

Answer (score 1):

I love [RegExBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

For your example above `([a-z]+)` it gives

```
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([a-z]+)»
   Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “ ” literally « »
```

and for

```
([a-z])([0-9]{5})
```

it explains as

```
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([a-z])»
   Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([0-9]{5})»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{5}»
      Exactly 5 times «{5}»
```

I find it fantastic for testing/creating RegExes.

Comment: This is nice for developers, but I need something more compact. My fault: I didn't mention how I am going to. My goal is to display description of regexp for users of website. So it needs to be really simple.

Comment: @user1019812, better add that to your original question. Also, does it need to account for the more advanced features, like look-arounds, backreferences, etc.?